# Text not in element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a slider from a bootstrap slider, and when I try to add text on the controllers, text display's on the left, when elements is on center.

Live demo: http://povilasc.lt/shop/

[image: photo] background changed to see text (1 and 2)

html:

```css
.carousel-indicators {
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #222;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
 <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Comment: added code. thanks for notice.

Comment: In snippet everything is like I want. But on webpage (on chrome, maybe on other browsers) text is out of elements. And I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Changed screenshot for better view.

Comment: Look at your code, Set `text-indent:` on `.carousel-indicators li` to `0px`. The bootstrap.min.css file sets `text-indent:` to `-999px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari the build in element inspector shows me, that your .carousel-indicators li have the style "text-indent: -999px;" applied.

Add to your .carousel-indicators li the style text-indent: 0px; and it should work.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I removed it on my style but forgot to remove on bootstrap.

Comment: @RILEYW1 one tip i can give you, never change or update your original bootstrap file. Always overwrite the default library/framework css code inside of your own "app.css" file.